# Javascript Object.Property logging undefined

Tags: javascript, object, undefined

`printPerson` takes an object as an argument, its loop iterates trough all its properties and is suposed to print them all out.

As you can see I've logged both the `person` and `property` variables and they are working fine. `person` is identified as an object, and `property` as a string with the correct property name, indicating that the loop is also working fine. But when it comes to logging `person.property`, the return value is `undefined`.

What am I missing?

```
var bob = {
    firstName: "Bob",
    lastName: "Jones",
    phoneNumber: "(650) 777-7777",
    email: "bob.jones@example.com"
};

var mary = {
    firstName: "Mary",
    lastName: "Johnson",
    phoneNumber: "(650) 888-8888",
    email: "mary.johnson@example.com"
};

var contacts = [bob, mary];

function printPerson(person) {
    for (property in person){
      console.log(person);
      console.log(property);
      console.log(person.property);
    }
}

function list(){
    for (var i=0;i<contacts.length;i++){
        printPerson(contacts[i]);
    }
}

list();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use bracket notation when using variables as keys:

```
console.log(person[property]);
```

Here are the relevant docs: [MDN on Objects Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)